# Restricting node reference values to owner

Tags: 7, views, entities, nodes

I have played with a bunch of modules (Node Reference Node Access, Views Field, View Reference) and can't seem to find one that does a very simple job; In one content type I want a field that provides a select list of all nodes owned by current user from another content type.

Think of it (roughly) as blog content types.

- Blog 1 - Owned by user 1
- Blog 2 - Owned by user 2
- Blog 3 - Owned by user 1

In another content type (updates) we'll have a field that is used for building a relationship (ie, select the blog that this update will be related to) and that field should be populated with the blogs owned by that user;

- Select Blog (for user 1 the list would contain;

  - Blog 1
  - Blog 3

I have read so much, installed so many modules and I just cant get it to work. The closest I have got is a field that contained the name of the view, which is not overly helpful.

**EDIT:**
Screen Shots:
[image: Manage Fields]
[image: Top section of Field edit]
[image: Bottom section of Field edit]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I managed to get this working in Drupal 7.

1. Install the very latest development snapshot of [Views 3](http://drupal.org/project/views).
2. Install the very latest development snapshot of [Chaos tools suite](http://drupal.org/project/ctools).
3. Install [References](http://drupal.org/project/references) beta-3.
4. Enable the Views UI module and the Node References module that comes with References.
5. Create a new view.
6. Add a 'References' display to that view - note, this is a special Views display type that you get from installing the References module - it is not a Page or Block display.
7. Add a Node reference field to your content type. You will now be able to select the Views display that you created in step 6 to filter the list of nodes that can be referenced. You do this in the 'VIEWS - NODES THAT CAN BE REFERENCED' fieldset.
   [image]

Comment: obviously be careful about relying on dev snapshots!

Comment: Yes. I didn't actually test this with the latest 'stable' versions, so it may be worth trying with those too.

Comment: Thanks Tom! Still getting 'broken/missing handler' errors when adding filters though... Any ideas?

Answer (score 5):

If I understand you right, you can use a View as the source for the nodereference widget, and give it appropriate filters to only show nodes of a certain type authored by the current user. To use a view (assuming you have Views installed and appropriate perms) you can

- edit the nodereference by going to *Content management* -> *Content types* -> *Edit [whatever content type]* -> *Manage fields* -> *[whatever field name]*;
- in the fieldset *Global settings* click to expand the fieldset *Advanced - Nodes that can be referenced (View)*;
- select the appropriate view in *View used to select the nodes*;
- if you want to use arguments you can specify them in *View arguments*.

Comment: No, thats exactly right, but I could not see where in the Nodereference widget to specify a View as the source.

Comment: @Christian, are you ok now, or would you like some more details?

Comment: Hi Andy, sorry for the delay. I can't see anywhere to set the view as the source. Do I need to create a certain view type? Or is there a module I need? Thanks!!

Comment: @Christian I've updated the answer - post back here if there are still troubles!

Comment: Andy, I'm sorry to be so much trouble, but I dont have a 'Global Settings' fieldset. Nothing in the Nodereference field looks anything like what you mentioned.

Comment: @Christian no worries, take a look at my additional info in the answer - if that doesn't help, could you add a screenshot of the screen you get?

Comment: Hi Andy, I have added the screen shots, thanks. Gonna add a bounty too cause you deserve more than my thanks.

Comment: @cristian, D7 has node reference in core but not the views options for it.

Comment: Someone downvoted, any comments?

Comment: @Christian - looks like you've got an answer! report back if it still doesn't work.

Answer (score 2):

For D7 you will need to use the [references](http://drupal.org/project/references) module, this allows you to filter by a view much in the way that Andy has described in his question.

*note: beta-2 which should have the code in has only just come out (may 7th) so even if you tried it before it is worth downloading again.*

Comment: I think I may have hit a bug with views 3, I keep getting 'Broken/missing handler' messages instead of the filters I am adding ...

Comment: You may find some of your modules need upgrading to work with views 3