# Override nodereference_autocomplete functionality

Tags: 7, entities, nodes

I would like to edit the functionality contained in nodereference_autocomplete() so that it will only return a subset of all nodes. What would be the best way to override this default functionality?

Comment: Since we're having a huge discussion below about what you're intentions are, please clarify what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This isn't exactly the same question, but I think [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3045/restricting-node-reference-values-to-owner/3046#3046) is just as valid.

> If I understand you right, you can use a View as the source for the nodereference widget, and give it appropriate filters to only show nodes of a certain type authored by the current user. Or have I got the wrong end of the stick?!

Answer (score 0):

An autocomplete function is, in Drupal 6, registered as menu callback. For example, this is the code used by user.module to register the function that autocompletes the usernames.

```
function user_menu() {
  $items['user/autocomplete'] = array(
    'title' => 'User autocomplete', 
    'page callback' => 'user_autocomplete', 
    'access callback' => 'user_access', 
    'access arguments' => array('access user profiles'), 
    'type' => MENU_CALLBACK, 
    'file' => 'user.pages.inc',
  );

  // …
}
```

If you want to alter the autocomplete function defined from a module, you just implement [hook_menu_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--hooks--core.php/function/hook_menu_alter/6) to alter the menu callback definition that uses the autocomplete function as menu callback.