# How do I modify the content of a select list field?

Tags: 7, forms, nodes

I have a content type with a [Node Reference](http://drupal.org/project/references) field, so the user can select from a list of node titles. I need to filter out some nodes from the list (those that have a date field older than the current date).

I know that [hook_form_alter()](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules--system--system.api.php/function/hook_form_alter/7) can be used to modify the display and validation of form fields, but probably not change the query that the field uses. So I think I need to write some kind of preprocess function for this field, that does a second filter on the contents?

Any pointers on how to do this would be great - thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at [Restricting node reference values to owner](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/3045/restricting-node-reference-values-to-owner)

As described there, you can select a view as the source for the node reference selection. In that view, you can apply whatever conditions you want to that list.